# Hashtable not follow java naming rule?

Tags: hashtable, naming, conventions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the ‘t’ in Hash Table(Hashtable) in Java not capitalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506706/why-is-the-t-in-hash-tablehashtable-in-java-not-capitalized)

Why java.util.Hashtable not follow java naming convention ? here  't' is lowercase, if it follow the class name would be HashTable...

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.HashMap;
java.util.HashSet;
java.util.Hashtable
```

> Because Map and Set are the Interfaces which come under Collection
>   Framework,  but table is not a keyword in current version. So
>   camelcase is not used.

Comment: you mean, if there is a interface with name Table ..the Hashtable would become HashTable?

Comment: Yes i think so..it does inherit Map too incase of HashMap....

Answer (score 0):

Hashtable was created in Java v1 not like other which were released in Java2.

Answer (score -1):

See this question:

[Why is the 't' in Hash Table(Hashtable) in Java not capitalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506706/why-is-the-t-in-hash-tablehashtable-in-java-not-capitalized)

> Hashtable was created in Java v1. The consistent naming conventions
>   for collections were established later, in Java2, when the other
>   classes were published as part of the brand new Java Collection
>   Framework.
>
> Which btw made Hashtable obsolete, so it should not be used in new
>   code.
>
> Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, am not fully satisfied upon this answer... Java's naming conventions are not a new one...By just capitalize the letter 't' what cause problem to java developers?

Comment: It is a new one. Java2 is considered new, compared to the older ones. Capitalizing the letter would prohibit reusing old sources. And, as @RKushmer quoted, Hashtable is obsolete. Should not be used for new designs.